# Get sentence without a word after special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, preg-match

How can i have the whole sentence without the first word which is preceded by special character ?

for example if i have this sentence:

```
 @jonson where are you?
```

i want get just this

```
  where are you?
```

and if its like that

```
   where are you @jonson ?
```

i want get

```
    where are you?
```

i know how to get the word after `@` like that :

```
    var moo = "@jonson where are you?".match(/@([^ ]*)/)[1]; // jonson
```

hope it can be done , because i need to get that sentence.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use string replace:

```js
 var moo = "@jonson where are you?".replace(/@\w*/,'');

document.write(moo)
```

you're matching the `@` character
followed by any word-character( `\w` ) , in any quantity ( `*` );

Comment: it works :) , please just explain me how your pregmatch works and everything is excelent :) . thanks